# getting empty results from scrapy crawler

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Crawler was working normally and doing fine job, but suddenly it stopped working properly. It follows pages but doesn't pull items from [here](http://mobi.ge/?page=products&category=60).

And here is the crawler:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MobiItem(Item):
    brand = Field()
    title = Field()
    price = Field()

class MobiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mobi2"
    allowed_domains = ["mobi.ge"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://mobi.ge/?page=products&category=60"
    ]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("\?page=products&category=60&m_page=\d*", ))
            , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        blocks = sel.xpath('//table[@class="m_product_previews"]/tr/td/a')
        for block in blocks:
            item = MobiItem()
            try:
                item["brand"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/text()").extract()[0].strip()
                item["model"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
                item["price"] = block.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
                yield item
            except:
                continue
```

Examining the xpath didn't give any suspicious results.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyze the logs and instead of this:

```
        try:
            item["brand"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item["model"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item["price"] = block.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            yield item
        except:
            continue
```

do

```
        try:
            item["brand"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item["model"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item["price"] = block.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            yield item
        except Exception as exc:
            self.log('item filling exception: %s' % exc)
            continue
```

I think you might be getting `IndexError` exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ran the spider and this is what I got in the terminal for all pages:
`2014-05-01 12:07:04+0200 [mobi2] DEBUG: item filling exception: 'MobiItem does not support field: model'`

Comment: `MobiItem` class doesn't have field `model`. It has field `title`. Replace `item["model"] = block.xpath` with `item["title"] = block.xpath`

Comment: Ah yes, was my mistake when I was rewriting the spider. It worked, scraped the items with few `DEBUG: item filling exception: list index out of range` in the log. but it did the job. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what was the problem :)

Comment: `list index out of range` means that `extract()[0]` is working on an empty list, which means that some of the xpath queries didn't work.